# Scp as background job?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, nohup

Here is the problem:

1. i must move some files from one host to another, ok i use scp for
   it.
2. But i need use it without blocking console, so should use scp &. But my job will killed after disconnecting (a heard it`s something called hup signal) so i found some tricks for fixing this.
3. But i wanna see progress bar after some time and all that tricks couldnt work because when i use jobs - it display jobs that only for these session.

So how to fix my problem ?
P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is what you want but I'll suggest [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). It allows you to run a program so that when you log out, the program continues execution in the background. Later you can log back in and resume interaction with the program.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want ability to [detach -and- attach](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/) terminal - The tool is called screen.